# Is it possible to play the rendered animation backwards continuously via the built in player?

Tags: animation, interface

I have recently been using the various commands for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> (*Play Rendered Animation*) window, and it's great. However I have noticed that pressing the <kbd>→</kbd> key will keep cycling through the rendered frames, and that pressing the <kbd>←</kbd> key (reverse) will result in the playback stopping at the first frame (0001).

Is it possible to change this behavior? And if not, does anybody know why it is set up this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is not possible to do this using the arrow keys, there is a way to do it.

- **<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> use backward playback.**
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> use forward playback.

Using these key commands you can toggle between forwards and backwards playback.

See also the [**manual**](http://blender.org/manual/render/display.html).

Answer (score 3):

When playing in build-in player, you can hold <kbd>LMB</kbd> then drag towards left / right for manual scrubbing. Some other commonly-used features:

- <kbd>P</kbd> to toggle ping-pong mode.
- <kbd>0</kbd> to toggle loop.
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start playing when paused.

Comment: Nice features, but it doesn't exactly answer the question :-/

Comment: Then feel free to accept your own answer.  :)

Comment: I can't yet, there is a two day limit . . .

Comment: @LeonCheung congrats to 10k!

Comment: @stacker Thank you! Cheers buddy, happy blending! :D